# Combine 2 networks with one Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have 2 NIC on my Windows Server 2008 machine. One Card connected with clients via router and is leasing IPs to clients. The second card is connected with switch provided by ISP. Now Server machine is connected with Internet but clients are not getting internet access.
Urgent help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You'll need the Routing and Remote Access role installed

Comment: Can I install RRAS role on the same machine on which I have added the role of DHCP?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said you would need to install the Routing and Remote Access role. Then you would probably want to set up the server NAT on the server to share the internet connection. There is a pretty decent tutorial for configuring RRAS for NAT [here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/Using-Windows-Server-NAT-Router.html).